# passing multiple statements in ocaml using "in" and "and" operations

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I wanted to convert this C++ code to ocaml, but i'm getting syntax error

C++ code

```
int** matrix(int n,int **a,int**b)
{
t=n/2;
a11=new int*[t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    a11[i]=new int [t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    for(j=0;j<t;j++)
        a11[i][j]=a[i][j];

a12=new int*[t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    a12[i]=new int [t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    for(j=0;j<t;j++)
        a12[i][j]=a[i][j+t];

a21=new int*[t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    a21[i]=new int [t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    for(j=0;j<t;j++)
        a21[i][j]=a[i+t][j];
}
```

Ocaml code

```
let matrix n x y =
let t = n/2 in
        let a11 = Array.make_matrix t t 0 in
        for i = 0 to t-1 do
            for j = 0 to t-1 do
            a11.(i).(j) <- x.(i).(j)
            done
        done            
        and
        a12 = Array.make_matrix t t 0 in
        for i = 0 to t-1 do
            for j = 0 to t-1 do
            a12.(i).(j) <- x.(i).(j+t)
            done
        done        
        and
        a21 = Array.make_matrix t t 0 in
        for i = 0 to t-1 do
            for j = 0 to t-1 do
            a21.(i).(j) <- x.(i+t).(j)
            done
        done
;;
```

The problem is that the value of t is not getting passed inside the a12 and a21 arrays and it is getting unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `and` for a `let` can't appear in the body of the let. Instead, use multiple lets:

```
let matrix n x y =
  let t = n/2 in
  let a11 = Array.make_matrix t t 0 in
  for i = 0 to t-1 do
    for j = 0 to t-1 do
      a11.(i).(j) <- x.(i).(j)
    done
  done;
  let a12 = Array.make_matrix t t 0 in
  for i = 0 to t-1 do
    for j = 0 to t-1 do
      a12.(i).(j) <- x.(i).(j+t)
    done
  done;
  let a21 = Array.make_matrix t t 0 in
  for i = 0 to t-1 do
    for j = 0 to t-1 do
      a21.(i).(j) <- x.(i+t).(j)
    done
  done
```

Comment: Rather than having three separate `for` loops, one could also make the three matrices first and initialize them all within the same loop.

Comment: Yep, or you could have an inner function that takes an offset to add to `i` and `j`. How to factor isn't the OP's question, though...

Comment: @gsg Your first statement is incorrect, `let x = (let y = 1 and z = 2 in y + z)` is correct in ocaml. But otherwise I agree.

Comment: @Sheeft: that's the `and` for a different `let` (and isn't in the body of the `let`).

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood your statement then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the following has the same problem as your original code:

```
# let x = 4 in () and y = 7 in ();;                
Error: Syntax error
```

Since `let` defines an expression, this amounts to writing `() and ()`, which indeed is not legal OCaml.

The correct use of `let ... and` looks like this:

```
# let x = 4 and y = 7 in ();;
Warning 26: unused variable x.
Warning 26: unused variable y.
- : unit = ()
```

There are several `let ... and let ...` but just *one* `in`.